# How to check .NET version from browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a C# program that is run over a web browser. One of the things the web page does is use javascript to check to ensure that .NET is installed on the machine before running. Currently this is done by using the userAgent string which, from my research is an unreliable method. Also it only works on IE. Is there a browser agnostic way to do this in javascript or vbnet or really anything I can do from a page?

Currently what we have is:

```
function isDOTNETInstalled() {

    var ag = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ag.indexOf("IE") != -1 || ag.indexOf('Trident') != -1) {
        if (ag.indexOf(".NET4.0") != -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.write("The automatic detection of the .net framework only works in Internet Explorer.");
    }

    //return false;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible as it would be a security risk. Javascript executing in the browser should have minimal awareness about the machine on which it is operating on. What access rights it does have would be dependent on what the browser allows access to so even if you found something that worked in one browser (like IE) chances are it would not work on other browsers (like chrome or firefox).

Comment: I really doubt that this kind of information would be knowingly leaked by recent browsers as it's revealing information that could potentially used to attack the target.

Comment: Side note - how does your program run over the browser? Is it downloaded and then executed or maybe installed? Could you package it in such a way that the installer does a check instead of the browser?

Comment: Igor, it's sent over the browser and downloaded to the machine and executed there. No installation other than dropping the EXE. We are moving to Java Webstart for the time being due to a lack of better options but at the moment, a .NET application is sent over the browser, executed and then pulls java files over that are run locally. I was hoping I could do something quickly because some users are complaining that we still force the use of IE because of this .NET check.